# Open strings and semitones on a classical guitar

Tags: scales, classical-guitar, self-learning, chromatic

My son in learning guitar, however how do you raise a note up 2 semitones when it is an open string for example open 1st string in e and we want to raise it 2 chromatic semitones.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to tune the E string so it's an F#?

Comment: Fret the string on the second fret (if this is what you're asking). Each fret corresponds to one semi-tone.

Answer (score 2):

Each and every fret on a guitar represents one semitone. Thus to move from a C, 1st fret, 2nd string, go up to 2nd fret for C#, and 3rd fret for D (+one tone - or two semitones). When the string is, say, an open E, then moving up one semitone by fretting fret 1, it plays F, and another fret up (fret 2) plays F#. Semitones are generally thought of as the 'chromatic' bits of music.As in, if you played several consecutive semitones, it would constitute  part of a chromatic scale.

Answer (score 0):

Simply consider open strings as the fret 0.
And raising a semitone is playing a fret up.

```
  1    2  ... semitones up  
|----|---|
E||-F-|-F#|-G-|-G#|--- e (1st)
-||---|---|---|---|--- B (2nd)   |
-||---|---|---|---|--- G (3rd)   |
-||---|---|---|---|--- D (4th)   |- Strings
-||---|---|---|---|--- A (5th)   |
-||---|---|---|---|--- E (6th) 
0   1   2   3   4  ...  <-----  FRET
```